# Loading Keras dataset mnist

Tags: keras-2

After installing `keras` `gpu`, I try the simple example:

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

Prints the following output:

```
2.2.4 

Using TensorFlow backend.
```

However, when I try to load a dataset:

```
form keras.datasets import mnist
```

It gives an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-12-3386782fae62>", line 1
    form keras.datasets import mnist
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form` is not a python keyword. Try `from`.

This is the import line from the [Keras datasets](https://keras.io/datasets/) page:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

Comment: This is embarrassing. I gave you credit, but I should just delete this thread.

Comment: Go ahead :). Glad I could help.